# Find, cut and paste regex in sublimeText3

Tags: regex, text, latex, pattern-matching, sublimetext3

I have the following in my text file:

```
53\footnote{Author Name, \textit{Book Title}, p..}
3\footnote{Author Another, \textit{Book Old}, p..}
5-6\footnote{Author Onemore, \textit{Book New}, p..}
```

I have a few hundred of these types of text. I have arrived here after using simple regex. It's Latex markup text. These are not in separate lines, they are in between the text. With regex, I want to move the digits at the beginning and placed like this: p.53. It should look like so:

```
\footnote{Author Name, \textit{Book Title}, p.53.}
\footnote{Author Another, \textit{Book Old}, p.3.}
\footnote{Author Onemore, \textit{Book New}, p.5-6.}
```

If not in Sublime, I can use any tool available on Linux.

Edit 1: There are a few numbers like years and dates in my text. So, the solution must avoid changing them. Also, the size of the footnotes varies in some cases. But `p..}` remains the same throughout.

Answer (score 2):

In Sublime, select **`Find → Replace…`**.

In the `Find:` field, enter

```
([\d-]+)(\\footnote.*?\}, p\.)
```

and in the `Replace:` field, put

```
\2\1
```

[image: screenshot of Sublime Text]

Explanation:

There are two capturing groups, enclosed in parentheses `()`. The first one captures one or more characters consisting of digits 0-9 (`\d`) and the hyphen character (`-`). This is the page number or page range, assuming there are no spaces between characters.

The second capture groups starts capturing at the `\footnote` LaTeX directive and selects all characters up to and including `}, p.`. We are now ready to replace, which is a very simple operation - just reverse the position of the two captured groups, signified by `\2\1` in the replace field.

See the [demo at regex101.com here](https://regex101.com/r/CmJRZu/1).

Again, this is assuming that all of your targets are formatted exactly as you've shown in the question, with no extraneous characters or spacing.

Comment: Not only I was able to do what I asked in my question, it helped to device regex for another solution I was looking for. It saved hours and hours highly error prone work.

Comment: @nixnotwin Glad to help, and good luck with the thesis!